# My system hangs very much even when multiple tabs are opened in browser. Android Studio and WebGL is not running on my system's browser

Tags: graphics, firefox, google-chrome, android-studio, 3d

I am using Ubuntu since last 3 years and recently I bought a new Dell system.
Then my life became difficult.
Android Studio when installed didn't run. And a build error was shown and the graphics area of the Android Studio does not show up.

There is an online 3D CAD modelling application online known as `Onshape.com`. When I opened it's editor window which uses WebGL, it didn't opened and gave an WebGL disabled error. I searched for this error but nothing helped.

I actually use two browsers, one is firefox and second is Chrome. And they both show the same errors.

When more than 10 tabs of Youtube are opened in my browser then usually system hangs. And it is very painful. When i close some tabs then the system starts running smoothly.

My point is that there is some problem with my Graphics driver of my System.

I can't use Android Studio. I can't use Onshape which is a 3d graphics program opened in browser.

Please help me.
I am so confused that after changing two more computers the problem is still here.
Ubuntu 16.04 is my operating system. Dell is my machine.

if anyone can engage with me to solve my issue.
I will appreciate him.

Answer (score 0):

### Onshape.com Problem

- Check if you have enabled WebGL:

  - For chrome **Open Google Chrome**. In the address bar, type chrome://flags/, and press Enter.
  - Scroll to **Disable WebGL** - Enabling this option prevents web applications from accessing the WebGL API, and click **Enable**
  - Restart chrome

[image]

### Android studio problem

I suggest to install it via snap:

```
sudo snap install android-studio
```